# Fixed sections in droppable TextArea JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, textarea

I need a text area where i can fix some labels and can drag and drop components under relevant label. It also should have the ability to rearrange components if droped under wrong label.
Can anyone please give me idea about its implimentation. It will be very helpful if you provide some sample code.
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
    $("#elements li b").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    $(".to_drop").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        // accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            
            var old = $(this).val();
            if (old == "") {
                $(this).val(ui.draggable.text());
            } else {
                $(this).val(old + ", " + ui.draggable.text());
            }
          

        }
    })
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <li><b>one</b> <b>two</b> <b>three</b></li>
    <li><b>one</b> <b>two</b> <b>three</b></li>
    <li><b>one</b> <b>two</b> <b>three</b></li>
    <li><b>one</b> <b>two</b> <b>three</b></li>
</div>
<textarea type="text" class="to_drop" ></textarea>
```

Comment: i  think you want this ?